# What loot does the boss drop?

Tags: steam-monster-game

In Steam Monster game, you wil occassionally encounter a boss level. One of the upgrades gives you 1% better chance to boss loot. The description doesn't tell us much.

> **Boss Loot**
>   Increases your chance to get loot after defeating a boss.
>   Base increased by: 1%.

What is this loot exactly? Just gold coins? Or something more tangible, like discounts, trading cards or something else in your Steam inventory?

Comment: Right now I only got usable items for the minigame itself. But I think you also get trading cards for killing bosses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only loot I've ever gotten from defeating bosses are consumables, like the type of stuff you can buy at the start of every day using your Badge Points or the single-use things towards the bottom of the store window.

If I return to the game after some time away, the screen is packed with notifications about the loot that the bosses have dropped in my absence.

Strategy-wise, I don't think 1% more boss loot is really worth it - there are a couple of these items that can be useful (ie, Cripple Spawner for instance) but most are minor, short-lived bonuses at best.

Comment: Some actually give permanent increases to your Crit or Health, and Treasure gives you 100k.